# jQuery Mobile showing doubled button

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I'm trying my first app with jQM+PhoneGap.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes" />
    <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      app.initialize();
    </script>
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="app" data-role="page">

      <div data-role="content">
        <a onClick="$(this).toggleClass('toggleOffButton');" data-role="button" class="toggleOnButton" id='toggleButton' data-corners="true" data-mini="false" data-theme="a" tabIndex="2"/>
      </div>
      <!-- /content -->

      <div data-role="footer">
        Footer
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /page -->
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see it is a really simple page.

The problem is that it outputs a double button instead of just one and it's driving me mad.

Replacing the

```
<a onClick="$(this).toggleClass('toggleOffButton');" data-role="button" class="toggleOnButton" id='toggleButton' data-corners="true" data-mini="false" data-theme="a" tabIndex="2"/>
```

with a string makes it print the string just one time as intended but the button is repeated twice.

Any ideas on what can be the problem?

I was reading something about including twice jQM scripts but, as you can see in the code, they're not double referenced!

Comment: use this instead of inline Javascript `$(document).on('click', '#toggleButton', function () { $(this).toggleClass('toggleOnButton'); });`

Comment: Still the same output

Comment: Are you using your own data-theme? although I'm not sure whether this is the problem.

Comment: No, everything is set to its default, no custom things here!

Comment: You don't need `mobile.structure` nor `mobile.theme`. Remove them and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your HTML and found your problem.

jQuery Mobile button created from an a tag element MUST be closed. Basically change this:

```
<a onClick="$(this).toggleClass('toggleOffButton');" data-role="button" class="toggleOnButton" id='toggleButton' data-corners="true" data-mini="false" data-theme="a" tabIndex="2"/>
```

to this:

```
<a onClick="$(this).toggleClass('toggleOffButton');" data-role="button" class="toggleOnButton" id='toggleButton' data-corners="true" data-mini="false" data-theme="a" tabIndex="2"/></a>
```

Also give it some text.

And like **[Omar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771795/omar)** told you in comments you don't need:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
```

if you have these to files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery mobile provides its own toggle buttons with a nice look.

```
<label for="flip-mini">Flip switch:</label>
<select name="flip-mini" id="flip-mini" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
<option value="off">Off</option>
<option value="on">On</option>
</select>
```

we can also explore here for further reference.
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/switch/